# How to organise rows in a union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having a little issue with my results where I am trying to create a fixture list for each team, playing home and away. I’ve almost got it working but the problem I have is displayed in the following results:

[image]

I have 2 teams playing each other in week 1 home and away and the same two teams playing each other home and away in week for.

What this should display when I insert the data and read it is week 1, team 4 is at home playing team 18 who are way, and then the reverse fixture is played in week 4.

In other words row 2 and 3 are incorrect and should only show rows 1 and 4. What do I need to change in the code below to get this to work?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Fixture (WeekNumber, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, FixtureDate, LeagueID)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.teamID ORDER BY h.TeamID, a.TeamID, h.LeagueID) AS WeekNumber,
    h.TeamID,
    a.TeamID,
    DATEADD(day,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY h.LeagueID)-1)*7,@StartFixtureWeek) AS FixtureWeek, 
    h.LeagueID
FROM dbo.Team h
CROSS JOIN dbo.Team a
WHERE h.TeamID <> a.TeamID
AND h.LeagueID = a.LeagueID
UNION
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.teamID ORDER BY h.TeamID, a.TeamID, h.LeagueID) AS WeekNumber,
    h.TeamID,
    a.TeamID,
    DATEADD(day,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.LeagueID)-1)*7,@StartFixtureWeek) AS FixtureWeek, 
    h.LeagueID
FROM dbo.Team h
CROSS JOIN dbo.Team a
WHERE h.TeamID <> a.TeamID
AND h.LeagueID = a.LeagueID


select * from dbo.Fixture
WHERE (HomeTeamID = 4 AND AwayTeamID = 18) OR (HomeTeamID = 18 AND AwayTeamID = 4)
```

UPDATE:

Below is an explanation and design of the desired output:

```
WeekNumber  HomeTeamID   AwayTeamID  FixtureWeek  LeagueID
1           1             4          10-06-2016         1
2           1             3          17-06-2016         1
3           1             2          24-06-2016         1
4           4             1          30-06-2016         1
5           3             1          06-07-2016         1
6           2             1          13-07-2016         1
1           2             3          10-06-2016         1
2           2             4          17-06-2016         1
3           3             4          24-06-2016         1
4           3             2          30-06-2016         1
5           4             2          06-07-2016         1
6           4             3          13-07-2016         1
1           5             8          10-06-2016         2
2           5             7          17-06-2016         2
3           5             6          24-06-2016         2
4           8             5          30-06-2016         2
5           7             5          06-07-2016         2
6           6             5          13-07-2016         2
1           6             7          10-06-2016         2
2           6             8          17-06-2016         2
3           7             8          24-06-2016         2
4           7             6          30-06-2016         2
5           8             6          06-07-2016         2
6           8             7          13-07-2016         2
```

Ok so have two leagues (LeagueID 1 and LeagueID 2)

In League 1 there are 4 teams (TeamID) – 1, 2, 3, 4 – They play each other home and away but they can’t play two games within the same week.

In League 2 there are 4 teams (TeamID) – 5, 6, 7, 8 – They play each other home and away but they can’t play two games within the same week.

Both Leagues start on the same day and add 7 days for every game (or in other words every week)

The output doesn’t show it but preferable if each team can play their home game one week and then the next week play away, then play home, then away etc. But if we can get the above output to display first and then fiddle about to order them home and away then that’s fine.

Comment: Which logic should you decide a team is `HomeTeam` or `AwayTeam`? I means why not **row 1 and 4** are incorrect, instead of **row 2 and 3** are incorrect? Or you only care about if `team 4` is `AwayTeam` in 2016/03/30 then they will be `HomeTeam` in 2017/01/11?

Comment: Why CROSS JOIN with WHERE, instead of regular INNER JOIN?

Comment: reason I used cross join is because I am calling from the same team table, but calling one team home team (h.teamID) and the other (a.teamID). I am a little new to SQL so any better approaches then let me know

Comment: Yeah if team 4 is home on the 11th, then when they are away in the reverse fixture, it will be on another day and another week

Comment: Does it matter when the reverse fixture is?  Is it always the following week or two weeks later, etc?

Comment: @destination-data No it doesn't matter when the reverse fixture is

Comment: First `CROSS JOIN` would generate all possible pairs between all teams. There is no need to `UNION` it with the second `CROSS JOIN`. The problem boils down to what logic you want to use to assign week numbers/dates. Show us a sample data with, say, 5 teams (or more). And show us what result you want to get for that sample data.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Will sort that out for you, give me 10 mins

Comment: @VladimirBaranov See update in question, thank you

Comment: @carlBrooks, you really should post that as a text, not image.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov changed it to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CROSS JOIN` with `h.TeamID <> a.TeamID` generates all pairs, i.e. `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`. I think it is easier if we separate them, so `WHERE` filter would become `h.TeamID > a.TeamID` or `h.TeamID < a.TeamID`.

Week numbers should be assigned for each League, so it should be partitioned by `LeagueID`. Then it is a matter of sorting teams in some way, and then in opposite direction.

In the result below you can see how a pattern of team pairs for 6 weeks repeat in two opposite directions.

Most likely it is possible to achieve the same or similar result with one `CROSS JOIN` that uses `<>` without `UNION` and a more complicated expression in `ROW_NUMBER`.

Side note: don't use `UNION` if you don't really need it. Use `UNION ALL`.

Side note 2: it doesn't matter if you use `CROSS JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` here. Optimizer would generate identical execution plans. I think `CROSS JOIN` here is more readable, shows more clearly the intention to generate a Cartesian product - set of all pairs.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (TeamID int, LeagueID int);

INSERT INTO @T (TeamID, LeagueID) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 2),
(6, 2),
(7, 2),
(8, 2);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    h.TeamID AS HomeTeamID
    ,a.TeamID AS AwayTeamID
    ,h.LeagueID
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY h.LeagueID ORDER BY h.TeamID, a.TeamID) AS WeekNumber
    ,1 AS SortOrder
FROM
    @T AS h
    CROSS JOIN @T AS a
WHERE
    h.LeagueID = a.LeagueID
    AND h.TeamID < a.TeamID

UNION ALL

SELECT
    h.TeamID AS HomeTeamID
    ,a.TeamID AS AwayTeamID
    ,h.LeagueID
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY h.LeagueID ORDER BY a.TeamID DESC, h.TeamID DESC) AS WeekNumber
    ,2 AS SortOrder
FROM
    @T AS h
    CROSS JOIN @T AS a
WHERE
    h.LeagueID = a.LeagueID
    AND h.TeamID > a.TeamID

ORDER BY
    LeagueID
    ,SortOrder
    ,WeekNumber
;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| HomeTeamID | AwayTeamID | LeagueID | WeekNumber | SortOrder |
+------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
|          1 |          2 |        1 |          1 |         1 |
|          1 |          3 |        1 |          2 |         1 |
|          1 |          4 |        1 |          3 |         1 |
|          2 |          3 |        1 |          4 |         1 |
|          2 |          4 |        1 |          5 |         1 |
|          3 |          4 |        1 |          6 |         1 |
|          4 |          3 |        1 |          1 |         2 |
|          4 |          2 |        1 |          2 |         2 |
|          3 |          2 |        1 |          3 |         2 |
|          4 |          1 |        1 |          4 |         2 |
|          3 |          1 |        1 |          5 |         2 |
|          2 |          1 |        1 |          6 |         2 |
|          5 |          6 |        2 |          1 |         1 |
|          5 |          7 |        2 |          2 |         1 |
|          5 |          8 |        2 |          3 |         1 |
|          6 |          7 |        2 |          4 |         1 |
|          6 |          8 |        2 |          5 |         1 |
|          7 |          8 |        2 |          6 |         1 |
|          8 |          7 |        2 |          1 |         2 |
|          8 |          6 |        2 |          2 |         2 |
|          7 |          6 |        2 |          3 |         2 |
|          8 |          5 |        2 |          4 |         2 |
|          7 |          5 |        2 |          5 |         2 |
|          6 |          5 |        2 |          6 |         2 |
+------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I'll have a play about with it Vladimir, thank yopu. Just one slight issue, the reason I used <> in the where clause was that it avoids a team playing against itself. Do you know an alternative instead to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: Well, `>` or `<` does ensure that the team doesn't play with itself as well. It also ensures that result has each pair of teams listed only once. Instead of having both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` in the result you'll get only `(a,b)` or `(b,a)`.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I realised when I looked at your results it does not seem to match mine. You have it so that after team 2 plays team 1 (row 1), Team 2's next game is played at week 4, when it should be on week 2, does that make sense?

Comment: @carlBrooks, yes, it makes sense. To be fair, your sample result in the question doesn't follow this rule either. I can't think of a simple algorithm that would shuffle the teams in this manner right now. It may turn out to be rather tricky, because you need to guarantee that the same team doesn't play twice in the same week. If you figure out the algorithm, update the question and somebody would be able to translate it into SQL.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, here is an algorithm I found a few hours ago that will be useful for you: http://www.mathscareers.org.uk/article/football-fixtures-whats-score/ . It uses a polygon based algorithm to create fixtures for a five a side league

Comment: @carlBrooks, good luck implementing this algorithm in SQL. I would not try it.

Comment: Cool Vladimir, thank you for your help. I will try to fiddle about still with this set base method and update you if I get anywhere